how to preview token swap results on solana raydium using python?
I want to see the exact amount of tokens received after swap on solana raydium with python?
For now I can just transfer it, but I'm not sure exactly how much I will receive:
    transaction = transfer.make_transaction(
        source='CtURxXpzn9aredXse2KNtyDMeVW627tL3p7DCucdv8bc',
        mint='DCzbhHu3YGnc8Vhez4YEMznQ38ad6WYGVYqeB4Wn3mie',
        dest='sPkypr2LBtF5Go87zYSn5fBtWxCDEcobWeQQxXHpxJR',
        owner=transfer.keypair.public_key,
        amount=1,
        decimals=9

    )
    transfer.send_transaction(transaction)

